# Multiple bars at top in iPad Screen

Tags: ios, ipad, custom-controls, uinavigationbar, uitoolbar

I want to know can we create 2 bars at top like in this screen shot. one top bar with multiple buttons and search bar and second one with the back button.

[image]

Comment: Use UINavigationBar as first bar, and add a UIView as next one..

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `UINavigationBar` from the `UINavigationController` and you can add on the view of your currently displayed `UIViewController` a `UIToolBar` right at the top of the view.